# How can I specify a login\password at runtime to connect Oracle via EF6 in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I am making login window to connect Oracle from my app (C# Entity Framework Code First from existing database). I want to make user able to set his own username\password to connect with DB. I tryed to change connection string in my DbContext, but it is doesn't work. Connection string seems to be changed, but provider returns invalid login\password exception. When I am trying to connect DB with connection string whitch has stored pass everything is ok. I think there is some security reasons for this behaivor. How can I propperly change connection string in runtime?
I am using VS 2017, Entity Framework 6, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 18.3, Oracle 11.2 Server.

App.config

```
name="ConnStrPass" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=titan;PASSWORD=REALPASS;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=BEE" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"

name="ConnStrNoPass" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=titan;PASSWORD=QWERTY;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=BEE" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
```

DBDemoModel.cs

```
public partial class DBDemoModel : DbContext
{
    public DBDemoModel()
        : base("name=ConnStrPass")
    {
    }

    //overriding constructor DBDemoModel to change pass in ConnectionString

    public DBDemoModel(string pass)
            : base("name=ConnStrNoPass")
    {

        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace("QWERTY", pass);

    }
```

AbonentsFinder.cs //works fine

```
    public List<ABONENTS> SelectAbonentsByName(string textToFind)
    {
        using (DBDemoModel db = new DBDemoModel())
        {
            var cont = db.ABONENTS.Where(a => a.OWNER.Contains(textToFind));
            var abon = cont.ToList();
            return new List<ABONENTS>(abon);
        }            
    }
```

AbonentsFinder.cs //doesn't work wrong username\login

```
    public List<ABONENTS> SelectAbonentsByName(string textToFind, string pass)
    {
        using (DBDemoModel db = new DBDemoModel(pass))
        {
            var cont = db.ABONENTS.Where(a => a.OWNER.Contains(textToFind));
            var abon = cont.ToList();  //exception
            return new List<ABONENTS>(abon);
        }            
    }
```

DBDemoModel.cs //System.NotSupportedException

```
    public DBDemoModel(string pass)
            : base(new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=titan; PASSWORD="+pass+";USER ID=BEE"), true)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was with EF profiler I used in my project. I disabled it and now everything works fine. OMG.

Answer (score 0):

All Oracle Database Configure i hope help for anyone. thanks

public static OracleConnection Connection;

```
    public static bool GetConnection()
    {
        String connectionString = "Data Source=Test;User ID=Test;Password=Test;";
        try
        {
            Connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            //Connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (OracleException ww)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ww.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int ExecuteStatement(string query)
    {
        if (fncOpenConnection(false))
        {
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, Connection);
                int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return rowCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalApp.ErrorMsg = ex.ToString();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else return -1;

    }

    public static int ExecuteStatement_TXN(string query)
    {
        if (fncOpenConnection(false))
        {
            OracleTransaction txn;
            txn = Connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {


                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, Connection);
                int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txn.Commit();
                return rowCount;

            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                GlobalApp.ErrorMsg = er.ToString();
                txn.Rollback();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else return -1;

    }




    public static OracleDataReader GetReader(string query)
    {
        fncOpenConnection(false);
        OracleDataReader dr = null;
        try
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, Connection);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return dr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return dr;

        }
    }


    public static DataTable GetTable(string query, int[] primaryKeyCol = null)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        try
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter oadp = new OracleDataAdapter(query, Connection);


            oadp.Fill(dt);


            if (primaryKeyCol != null)
            {
                DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[primaryKeyCol.Count()];
                int iCount = 0;
                foreach (int x in primaryKeyCol)
                {
                    keyColumns[iCount] = dt.Columns[x];
                    iCount = iCount + 1;
                }
                dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
            }



            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to login in order to change your password (similar to the way that most web sites will ask you for your CURRENT password first).

So let them login with their existing password, after which point you can run the following command through your connection object:

"alter user MY_USER identified by TheirNewPassword"

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. English is not my native language. I don't need to change my password, I need to spcify my login\password when I am connecting to DB.